# Name on domestic flight ticket in India

Tags: air-travel, tickets, india, domestic-travel

I booked an Indian domestic flight with my wife. I entered her first name as "Lakshmi" but her identification card says "Chaitanyalakshmi". Will this difference cause any problems?

Comment: I don't know about India, but in Europe and the US they will _not_ let her fly if the ID does not match the booking. I recommend you call the airline and explain it and get it corrected. They normally accept that if it is still time to the flight - they will probably _not- accept it the last days.

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue a couple of years ago on an IndiGo flight within India. My last name did not completely appear on the ticket because technically there was a space in my last name and the booking server did not allow that. I explained the situation at the time of check in and there was no issue.

However, the problem is actually being able to enter the airport as there is a verification at the entrance where they match the names on the ID card and the ticket. They are authorized to deny entry if they find this suspicious.

The best method is to call the airlines and get it corrected. It should not cost you any money.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my experience goes with domestic flights (Indigo, SpiceJet, AirAsia). I haven't faced any issue neither while entering into airport or while taking boarding pass. My wife has her surname (before marriage) in her passport while I always enter surname (after marriage).

so, I don't think that could be problem specially when you have got enough time to explain your issue in case you have been asked.

Comment: @pnuts Her first name is same but her surname use to be different from passport. Though, at airport they keep surname first but still no one had have complained about it yet (I had done around 8 domestic air travel with my wife in past 2 years). But as a saftey measure I keep my marriage certificate along with me.

Comment: The one I use to book tickets online. Lets say her name before marriage was " PQR, ABC" (the same is written on her passport, assume that ABC is her name and PQR is her old surname ), so when I am booking tickets online I use "Tripathi, ABC". Now, Even though surname appears in front I had have never been asked about the name.

Comment: @Pnuts Yes you are absolutely correct. Passport is still in her maiden name while I use her married name, always. Usually, I carry both passport with me and handle to officer whenever asked. No one has asked me anything about surname issue. I think, it is not show stopper for domestic airlines and even if that catch their eyes you can justify yourself. (I don't want to scare you but I personally found that staff of "Air India" is quite rigid in terms of policies but I have never seen or faced any issue with SpiceJet, Indigo or AirAsia).

Comment: @pnuts I keep you informed that I have sent to this query to my friend who handle International/domestic airport security and immigration check in India. I will let you know his response as soon as I get it. I can't say that it would be authentic (because legally you can not travel with incomplete name or incorrect name) but his response can give you assurance about worst case which may happen and how usually they handle it.

Comment: @pnuts I have just got response from my friend and he said that they usually ignore cases which seems to be legit, they aren't that strict for domestic flight but this is a serious concern for international one. I recommend you to keep copy of necessary documents along with you in case need them). **Though, I got a affirmative response claiming the generosity of security towards authentic cases but that's is still not recommended and airlines/airport authority holds all rights to refrain you from travelling.**